# Calling A Webservice in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a REST Api which needs Accountid, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret and a url to retrieve the account details.

My apex code look like this

```
<apex:page>
    <b>Hello World!</b>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Do something" action="{!doSomething}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and the Controller below

```
public with sharing class DetailButtonController
{

 String oauthkey='asdasdasd asd77cf6ef73b77';
 String oauthsecret='asdasdasdasd2195385b9aa2';
 String action='get';

        Http m_http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        String content = 'action='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(action, 'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oauthkey, 'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_secret='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('oauthsecret', 'UTF-8');

        req.setEndpoint('http://www.abc.com/api/1.0/accounts/2323.xml/');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');        
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setBody(content);

        httpResponse response = m_http.send(req);

}
```

So when the button is clicked it will call the url and read all xml responses.

There are 2 problems i am stuck on

1. the controller gives Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'http://www.abc.com/api/1.0/accounts/2323.xml/' at line 13 column 24

2.how to call this controller on click of that button

Comment: Can you post the Apex code you tried before? It'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have added the code and the 2 Questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't really compile... you don't have a method inside your class! :)

Try this instead (I am using the same "doSomething" method you already had):

```
public with sharing class DetailButtonController
{
  public string responseText {get;set;}

  public DetailButtonController() {
     responseText = '';
  } 

   public void doSomething() {

    String oauthkey='asdasdasd asd77cf6ef73b77';
    String oauthsecret='asdasdasdasd2195385b9aa2';
    String action='get';

    Http m_http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    String content = 'action='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(action, 'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oauthkey, 'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_secret='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('oauthsecret', 'UTF-8');

    req.setEndpoint('http://www.abc.com/api/1.0/accounts/2323.xml/');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');        
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(content);

    httpResponse response = m_http.send(req);

    responseText = response.getBody();
  }

}
```

Change your page to be:

```
<apex:page controller="DetailButtonController">
    <b>Hello World!</b>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Do something" action="{!doSomething}"/>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
          {!responseText}
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: `req.setMethod('GET');` should really be a `POST` so that the key & secret aren't exposed in the URL as visible parameters.

Comment: Good point Mark, I just changed the code. I was trying to get the OP unstuck using the obvious solutions and didn't even pay attention to the code itself.

Comment: @SebastianKessel The error is gone, how do i print the response?

Comment: I just changed my code to print the textual response from the API. Keep imn mind that there is no error handling or functionality in this sample.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Error: Unknown property 'DetailButtonController.responseText'

Comment: Make sure to make changes to the controller before you make changes to the page. I also made a small change to properly initialize the variable,.

Comment: @SebastianKessel got it working, one more error now i see in the XML, what can be the issue, the error is "oauth consumer key and/or signature not included in request parameters or authorization header"

Comment: Since that is a completely different error, I would recommend you mark your question as "accepted" and open a new one.  That way other people will be able to weigh in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33541/discussion-between-user580950-and-sebastian-kessel).